# Throw error on mysql warning pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to throw an exception if there is only a mysql warning and not an error.

In my case there should be an exception if a user tries to change the field `amount` to an negative value. (`amount` is an unsigned integer)

```
 try {
  $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
  $upd = $this->pdo->prepare("
      UPDATE Item set amount=amount-:amount where id = :itemID
  ");
  $upd->bindValue(":amount", $amount);
  $upd->bindValue(":itemID", $itemID);
  $upd->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $this->pdo->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: that's not PDO's job. Normally you'd use a constraint, but mysql doesn't support those, so you'd need to put a trigger on the table and fail the query if amount would go negative. that or you need to FETCH the value, check the result yourself in client-side code, and simply not run the update - which also opens the door to race conditions.

Comment: Is there any way to get the warning message? Is it reasonable to run a
`Show warnings` query?

Comment: no. that's abusing the php warnings system. warnings are for code-level problems, not managerial/logistical problems.