# MySQL/MariaDB Configure Warnings to throw Errors

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, warnings

**I need MySQL/MariaDB to throw error messages instead of warning messages.**

**Reason:** In my development environment, warnings are ignored in SQL/PHP (and both SQL and PHP continue processing), therefore I can't detect any issues when testing. In production, however, all warnings crash the query, thus terminating the API, and returning a "failure" message to users.

**This is a very bad result and caused many headaches in the past.**

**Here is a very specific scenario that caused many problems:**

I have a table "testtable" with two columns "pk" and "bRequiredBoolean", where pk is the primary key (thus auto increments) and bRequiredBoolean HAS NO DEFAULT VALUE:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`testtable` ( `pk` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `bRequiredBoolean` BOOLEAN NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`pk`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

In my development server, I can run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `testtable`() VALUES ()
```

and receive the following warning:

```
Warning: #1364 Field 'bRequiredBoolean' doesn't have a default value
```

In my development server, the entry IS INSERTED and the API continues executing.

In my production server, the entry ISN'T INSERTED and the API crashes.

**I know that the development/testing servers should be identical to prevent issues like this, but I currently don't have the funds for extra licenses, so I would like an alternative solution to throw error messages instead of warnings to catch scenarios like the one mentioned above.**

**Important note:** I don't want to insert any extra code within each query, I'd prefer to edit some configuration file. For instance, I don't want to add the following code TO EVERY SINGLE QUERY:

```
SHOW COUNT(*) WARNINGS
```

I'd rather edit some configuration file so it will always throw an error, even if I do ad-hoc queries directly through the GUI.

I found other similar questions, but nobody has responded to those threads:

[MariaDB shows warnings instead of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69436844/mariadb-shows-warnings-instead-of-errors)

[Throw error on mysql warning pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858515/throw-error-on-mysql-warning-pdo)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Compare your SQL_MODE in the two environments.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar! That's exactly what I needed to solve my issue. I've added the official answer that solves my problem below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar's comment, I found the solution to my problem.

You can check your SQL_Mode via:

```
SELECT @@SQL_MODE;
```

Apparently, there is a SQL_Mode setting that specifically throws errors for all warnings called **"Traditional"**

You can view the official mySQL website for more info regarding SQL_Mode values: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-full

So I ran the following query:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL';
```

After running the query, I executed the same query as before:

```
INSERT INTO `testtable`() VALUES ()
```

and received the following error:

```
Error
SQL query: Copy


INSERT INTO `testtable`() VALUES ();
MySQL said: Documentation

#1364 - Field 'bRequiredBoolean' doesn't have a default value
```

**This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much @Barmar!**

Comment: this will szillnot show all warnings as error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289205/how-can-i-make-fatal-errors-of-all-mysql-warnings